# css trim top and bottom of line

Tags: html, css, line, padding

I am trying to add a line(solid border, color) to a td. How can I trim line top and bottom with 2 px or add padding top and padding bottom to line?

My expected output would be 
I have a black border for a td with height 10 px. I want to make top 2px and bottom 2 px of that line to white color or apply 2 px padding to that line.

I am trying to separate 2 tds in a table with icons in side each td.I am trying to add a line between 2 tds with a line. I am adding border style of td to make it look like a line. I want that line height to be small and not touching td top and bottom borders.

[My code in fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fA9j/)

```
.leftLine {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: lightgray;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    height: 2px;
}
.icoContainer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
}
```

[image: Current]
[image: expected result]

Comment: I don't get what is your expected result, can you elaborate more on it?

Comment: My expected output would be 
I have a black border for a td with height 10 px. I want to make top 2px and bottom 2 px of that line to white color or apply 2 px padding to that line.

Comment: I don't get it. At least provide a simple sketch for us to understand. :)

Comment: I am trying to separate 2 tds in a table with icons in side each td.I am trying to add a line between 2 tds with a line. I am adding border style of td to make it look like a line. I want that line height to be small and not touching td top and bottomn borders.

Comment: I updated question with diagrams. I am expecting space on top and bottom of line.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the spacing just use `padding-top: ***px` and `padding-bottom: ***px` in each `<td>`.

Similar for the borders: `border-top: solid black 2px` and `border-bottom: solid black 2px`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get your Question:
But according to my understanding you are trying to give left border to a single td and you want its height should be small.
This cannot be achieved by adding border style to td direcetly.
I would suggest to use below code:
CSS CODE would be:

```
.leftLine {
border-left: solid black 1px;
margin: 0px;
padding : 0px;  
}
.icoContainer {
text-align: center;
padding-top : 5px;  
      padding-bottom: 5px;  
}
h1{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Add "leftLine" css to the innder div of the TD.
and you can change padding of "icoContainer". 
This will add padding to TD and border to inner div.
Please let me know if my understanding about your question is correct.

Comment: I updated question with diagrams. I am expecting space on top and bottom of line.

Comment: Use the above Css and add border to tr this will do the required.

Comment: I have created an example. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/jayendra_gothi/sL29L/